# Docker build fails with "The command '/bin/sh -c yarn install' returned a non-zero code: 1"

Tags: docker, jenkins, build, yarnpkg

I have a react project which is built inside docker with the next config:

```
FROM alpine:3.14 as build

RUN apk add --update nodejs npm
RUN npm install -g yarn
RUN yarn set version berry
RUN yarn set version latest

RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true

RUN apk add --no-cache autoconf automake g++ git libtool libpng-dev make nasm python3 py3-pip

ARG NODE_ENV
ARG APP_URL
ARG ENV_TYPE
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
ENV ENV_TYPE=${ENV_TYPE}
ENV APP_URL=${APP_URL}
ENV API_URL=${APP_URL}
ENV CHAT_URL=${APP_URL}

COPY . $HOME
WORKDIR $HOME


RUN yarn cache clean
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn run build-stage-env-prod

FROM nginx:1.15.3-alpine as final
COPY --from=build /home/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /home/app/lighthouse.html /usr/share/nginx/html/lighthouse.html
COPY --from=build /home/app/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /home/app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

When I run this on a local machine, everything looks fine, but when it's run by Jenkins it fails with the next error:

(the end of log)

```
➤ YN0000: Failed with errors in 20s 322ms
The command '/bin/sh -c yarn install' returned a non-zero code: 1
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

So, the error happens on the yarn install. How to debug it?

May the "The remote archive doesn't match the expected checksum" in on package be the source of the build fail?